# R Server: Panes on the left side are mutually exclusive

Tags: r, google-chrome, pane, r-server

I just started working at a new, blank R server in Chrome. However, from the beginning the two panes on the left side of the screen (the script in the upper, the console in the lower half) are mutually exclusive. What this means, is that they can not be viewed at the same time as it is usually the case. R is only showing one of them maximized on the left half of the screen.

If I try to change the size of the currently open pane using one of the two buttons on the top right corner of the panel, R is minimizing the other. The same is happening, if I use Ctrl+Shft+1. Interestingly, I can't manually change the relative size of those two panels but I can change manually the relative size of all panels horizontally.

Flipping the arrangement of console and source pane doesn't solve the problem. Changing the arrangement keeps the problem at the same place: whatever two panes I am putting at the left side, R only shows one maximized and hides the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that the relative size of the panes was maxed out, so that moving the mouse to the absolute end or to the absolute beginning of the pane brought up the cross cursor in just a small area. Finding this spot allowed to manually change the relative size so that both panes are visible again at the same time.